# How do I switch to IE8 compatibility mode in IE9?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, ie8-compatibility-mode

As title says - I need a way of viewing a page in IE8 compatibility mode. The option to do this isn't found in developer tools and I can't seem to find any compatilibty settings in the browser's tool menu.

Answer (score 0):

you should see a small broken paper icon next to the url bar -> [image], click it.

http://windows.microsoft.com/is-IS/windows7/How-to-use-Compatibility-View-in-Internet-Explorer-9

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line of text as first dom element after 'head' element.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8">
```

Can also switch to "IE=EmulateIE7" to emulate IE7.